# iOS8 - distributing Enterprise app via itms / MDM

Tags: ios8, enterprise, mdm, in-house-distribution

In IOS6 and 7 we have been successfully distributing an iPad enterprise app using the *itms* method via a page on our client's website.  This was simple and reliable for the client.

In iOS8 (as others have noted) the documentation for *itms* distribution has disappeared, and the auto-generation of the manifest plist has disappeared in Xcode 6.

*itms* download still works for us, with the downside that the current app is no longer backgrounded when an itms download starts.

However, Apple are presumably moving away from supporting *itms*. The documentation now just says:

```
  "Distribute the iOS App Store Package using MDM."
```

We have no experience of MDM at all. I would greatly appreciate pointers at the best / easiest way to move forward in this direction before *itms* becomes unsupported.

Liz

Answer (score 1):

You can begin by having a look to this MDM description by Apple : https://www.apple.com/uk/support/business-education/mdm/

Apple is providing a free MDM solution with Mac OS X Server "Profile Manager" which can help you try an end-to-end MDM solution : https://www.apple.com/uk/support/osxserver/profilemanager/

Mehdi