# How to distribute iOS 8.0+ enterprise apps over the air?

Tags: ios8, mdm, ota, enterprise-distribution

I have read several StackOverflow solutions to my question. I started with [Enterprise App Update Distribution on iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8)
and tried all provided answers. None helped or worked. I have also found other online solutions which were similar but didn't work either for iOS 8.0+ devices.

I currently run Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.5. with Xcode 6.1.1 on a late 2009 Mac Mini and an Mac Pro mid 2012 with Xcode 6.2 beta 5. I also have an enterprise developer account. So far I have spent a week working on this.

I have also read the apple docs [Distributing Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html) which say `"Distribute the iOS App Store Package using MDM for distributing your application in-house".`

1. Has anyone successfully distributed iOS 8.0+ apps without MDM using the old way (SSL server with .ipa and .plist file) this year (2015)?
   I don't want to waste another week if it won't work or is going to be obsolete. I found this so solution a bit helpful: [Distributing Enterprise Apps OTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097727/ios8-distributing-enterprise-app-via-itms-mdm)
2. Do I have to use MDM? Is MDM the only solution that I can use? I need to distribute my app over the air, the devices will not be able to connect to my mac mini or mac pro.
3. Could I use testFlight with an regular iOS development account instead going all the way with MDM vs. regular OTA on enterprise?

Any advice is welcome, since I never used MDM and enterprise OTA doesn't work fluidly.

Here is the index.html web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/octet-stream">
  <p> App Test links below: </p>

        <p> App for iOS 7.1 12.12. 09:45  v 0.71</p>
    <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://firmName.mywebPageName.com/app/AL.plist">
  Download APP </a>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://firmName.mywebPageName.com/app/AL.ipa</string>
                </dict>

                <dict>

                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>display-image</string>

                        <!-- optional. icon needs shine effect applied. -->
                        <key>needs-shine</key>
                        <true/>

                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110613172534/adwlauncher/images/1/19/Apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png</string>
                    </dict>

                    <!-- full-size-image: the large 512×512 icon used by iTunes. -->
                    <dict>

                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>full-size-image</string>

                        <!-- optional.  one md5 hash for the entire file. -->
                        <key>md5</key>
                        <string>61fa64bb7a7cae5a46bfb45821ac8bba</string>

                        <key>needs-shine</key>
                        <true/>

                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/1790/large_android/512/android_sh.png</string>
                    </dict>

            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.FirmName.AppName</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>APP 12.12.2014.</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Device logs :

```
iPad-FirmName backboardd[55] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 6->3
iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Pad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[449] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x17676360>
iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62:UserDictionary
    Using local storage: 1
iPad-FirmName softwareupdated[443] <Notice>: 00455000 : Unexpected XPC error on peer connection: Connection invalid
iPad-FirmName AssetCacheLocatorService[445] <Warning>: #dc22a225 [I:AssetCacheLocatorService.queue] found no caching servers
 iPad-FirmName nsurlsessiond[98] <Warning>: tcp_connection_set_timeframe Using minimum duration of 1 minute.
iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[449] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x17676360>
iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.FirmName2.AppName
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5352874684706439481.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 385)
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.FirmName2.AppName; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such process
iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57C9150C-36B5-4CCC-8107-6013CFF3260F
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/511F44AC-756E-4C13-A9AD-6DEFCC64BE75
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.08s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.69s; Overall: 0.77s
iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x165dca60> com.FirmName2.AppName (Placeholder) withPhase:3
iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.FirmName2.AppName.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x16736540> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[493] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "opportunistic" on <APSConnection: 0x16e111d0>
iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for com.FirmName2.AppName with icons
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5352874684706439481.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 385)
iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.FirmName2.AppName; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
:42 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:42 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.FirmName2.AppName is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/24BEC69A-A6E8-46A2-A913-289A3412308F
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE961BA2-422D-40F3-9C1A-BDB6A37A627A
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.11s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.67s; Overall: 0.79s
:43 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1669e500> com.FirmName2.AppName (Placeholder) withPhase:3
:43 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.FirmName2.AppName.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x16600220> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
:43 iPad-FirmName lsd[71] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x15e91560> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 3
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
Mar 10 11:32:28 iPad-FirmName backboardd[55] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 6->3
Mar 10 11:32:28 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar 10 11:32:31 iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[449] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x17676360>
iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62:UserDictionary
    Using local storage: 1
iPad-FirmName softwareupdated[443] <Notice>: 00455000 : Unexpected XPC error on peer connection: Connection invalid iPad-FirmName AssetCacheLocatorService[445] <Warning>: #dc22a225 [I:AssetCacheLocatorService.queue] found no caching servers
 iPad-FirmName nsurlsessiond[98] <Warning>: tcp_connection_set_timeframe Using minimum duration of 1 minute.
iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[449] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x17676360>
:40 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.FirmName2.AppName
:40 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5352874684706439481.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 385)
:40 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.FirmName2.AppName; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
:41 iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such process
:41 iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
:41 iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
:41 iPad-FirmName MobileStorageMounter[492] <Error>: 0x3af1f9dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
:41 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57C9150C-36B5-4CCC-8107-6013CFF3260F
:41 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/511F44AC-756E-4C13-A9AD-6DEFCC64BE75
:41 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.08s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.69s; Overall: 0.77s
:41 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x165dca60> com.FirmName2.AppName (Placeholder) withPhase:3
:41 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.FirmName2.AppName.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x16736540> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
:42 iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[493] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "opportunistic" on <APSConnection: 0x16e111d0>
:42 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:42 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:42 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for com.FirmName2.AppName with icons
:42 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5352874684706439481.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 385)
:42 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.FirmName2.AppName; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
:42 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:42 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.FirmName2.AppName is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/24BEC69A-A6E8-46A2-A913-289A3412308F
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.FirmName2.AppName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE961BA2-422D-40F3-9C1A-BDB6A37A627A
:43 iPad-FirmName installd[463] <Notice>: 0x357000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.11s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.67s; Overall: 0.79s
:43 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1669e500> com.FirmName2.AppName (Placeholder) withPhase:3
:43 iPad-FirmName itunesstored[385] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.FirmName2.AppName.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x16600220> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
:43 iPad-FirmName lsd[71] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x15e91560> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 3
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName filecoordinationd[152] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.FirmName2.AppName (bundle id com.apple.iaptransportd, 77A3EDE6-7CA7-46A7-AABE-C08BCBACFCEF)
:44 iPad-FirmName filecoordinationd[152] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.FirmName2.AppName (bundle id (null), A4079526-83C2-4C3A-9881-5741123F6A7F)
:44 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:44 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:44 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
:46 iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile waitForFileToDownload:](489): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x16636920>(0)
        permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip
        safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166def70>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62
        currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip

        storeName: UserDictionary
        modelVersionHash: SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=
        baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip

    Download failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file download timed out." UserInfo=0x1675db30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The file download timed out.}
:46 iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62:UserDictionary
    Using local storage: 0
:52 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
:53 iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[493] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x16e111d0>
:57 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
:58 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0:43 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:43 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:43 iPad-FirmName filecoordinationd[152] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.FirmName2.AppName (bundle id com.apple.iaptransportd, 77A3EDE6-7CA7-46A7-AABE-C08BCBACFCEF)
:44 iPad-FirmName filecoordinationd[152] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.FirmName2.AppName (bundle id (null), A4079526-83C2-4C3A-9881-5741123F6A7F)
:44 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
:44 iPad-FirmName kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
:44 iPad-FirmName lockdownd[25] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
:46 iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile waitForFileToDownload:](489): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x16636920>(0)
        permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip
        safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166def70>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62
        currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip

        storeName: UserDictionary
        modelVersionHash: SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=
        baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x166e4e00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip

    Download failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file download timed out." UserInfo=0x1675db30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The file download timed out.}
:46 iPad-FirmName kbd[153] <Warning>: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~10AB19CF-4235-5B4C-A68F-EAD867DC5A62:UserDictionary
    Using local storage: 0
:52 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
:53 iPad-FirmName syncdefaultsd[493] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x16e111d0>
:57 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
:58 iPad-FirmName locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: Before I answer, it would be very helpful if you provided your pertinent HTML as well as the PLIST it is pointing to. Showing your work is typically the best way to get results on SO.

Comment: Thanks. What do the device logs say when installation is attempted?

Comment: Updated with device logs. The app icon was presented on the device with the status of :"...waiting" and logs mention the error: "Download failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file download timed out." UserInfo=0x1675db30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The file download timed out.}" . The download server has a valid SSL certificat.

Comment: Did you enable the proper MIME settings on your webserver? Are you behind a firewall or some other web filter by any chance? Does your app install work on a non-iOS8 device?

Comment: 1. I didn't touch the MIME settings of the ws. 2. Nothing changed in the last few months in firewall settings/or web filter. It might not be because of this. 3. Yes it worked with non iOS8 devices with certain .plist edition and modification. Not always. This current build didn't work several times on iOS 7.1.2. But I will check this further. The problem with non iOS8 devices that I don't have any1 anymore. I will also check the MIME settings.

Comment: @MB_iOSDeveloper : How did you fix the issue, i am also facing same issue. Able to download the app in iOS7Device, not working in iOS8 device. Please help me out.

Comment: From iOS 8.2+ and XCode 6.2+ (non beta) the app distribution works. I do not know why and how. My current problem is that my server has problems with the SSL. Apple rejects the SSL certificate as not valid. I will have the SSL fixed since we have a new SSL since 05.04. The old SSL worked. Q1 - Which version of iOS8 is your app not working? Q2 Which Xcode version are you using?